# C#-Server and Java-Client: TCP Socket Communication Issues

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have wrote a server program in C# using `TCPListner` and a client program in  Java using socket but I fail to send complex objects from Java client to C# server.

When I send a simple string from Java client to C# server by converting the string into byte array,
it always show some invalid characters at the start of message when converted back to String (using `Encoding.utf8.getstring(bytesArray)` ) in C# server. When I pass a String from C# to Java Client it shows invalid Header error.

Please help me if any one have any alternative or know abut any free API which can solve my problem. I have tried `Java-cs-bridge` to send complex objects but it always show Exception on C# server.

Here is the code:

C# Server Code - Main Function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace netSocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

            var IP = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(ip =>ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Select(ip =>ip).FirstOrDefault();

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is Running at " + IP.ToString());


            TcpClient clientSocket = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected ... ");

            Writer wr = new Writer(clientSocket);
           wr.start(); 

            Reader r = new Reader(clientSocket);
            r.start();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

C# Server Reader Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace netSocketServer
{
    class Reader
    {
        TcpClient socket;
        NetworkStream ns;

        public Reader(TcpClient s)
        {
            socket = s;
            ns = socket.GetStream() ;
        }
        public void start() 
        {
            new Thread(
                t => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int size = ns.ReadByte();
                            byte[] buff = new byte[size];

                            ns.Read(buff,0,size);

                            String message = Encoding.UTF8.getString(buff);

                            Console.WriteLine("Message from Client : {0}",message);

                            ns.Flush();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected : " + e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }).Start();
        } 

    }
}
```

C# Server Writer Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace netSocketServer
{
    class Writer
    {
        TcpClient socket;
        NetworkStream ns;

        public Writer(TcpClient s)
        {
            socket = s;
            ns = socket.GetStream();
        }
        public void start() 
        {
            new Thread(
                t => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.Write("Please Enter your Message : ");
                            string Message = Console.ReadLine();
                            byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
                            byte size = (byte)Message.Length;
                            ns.WriteByte(size);
                            ns.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                            ns.Flush();
                        }
                        catch(IOException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected : " + e.Message);
                            socket.Close();
                            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Closse Server .... ");
                        }
                    }
                }).Start();
        } 

    }
}
```

Java Client - Main Function

```
package javaclient.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Numan
 */
public class JavaClientNet {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Socket socket;
        Read r;
        Writer wr;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        try 
        {
            // TODO code application logic here

            System.out.print("Please Enter Server IP : ");
            socket = new Socket(s.next(), 8888);

            wr = new Writer(socket);
            wr.start();

            r = new Read(socket);
            r.start();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());   
        }
    }
}
```

Java Client - Reader Class

```
package javaclient.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Numan
 */
public class Read extends Thread
{
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream inStream;

    Read(Socket s)
    {
        socket = s;
        try {
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     while(true)
     {
         try
         {
            String str;
            byte size = inStream.readByte();
            byte[] buf = new byte[size];
            inStream.read(buf);
            str = new String(buf);
            System.out.println("Message form Server : "+str);
         }
         catch(IOException e)
         {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             Thread.currentThread().stop();
         } 
     }   
    }
}
```

Java Client - Writer Class

```
package javaclient.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javacsconverter.core.tobyte.ToByteConvertHelper;

/**
 *
 * @author Numan
 */
public class Writer extends Thread
{
    Socket socket;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    Writer(Socket s)
    {
        socket =s;
        try 
        {
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {

                System.out.print("Please Enter Your Message : ");


                String str = scanner.nextLine();

                byte[] buff = str.getBytes();

                outStream.write(buff);

                outStream.flush();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### General notes

Please do not abort the threads (both C# and Java).

### C# Server

#### Program class

There is a data race because the static `Console` class is used by multiple threads:

1. Main thread: the `Program.Main()` method calls the `Console.Read()` method;
2. Worker thread: the `Writer.start()` method calls the `Console.ReadLine()` method.

Please consider replacing the `Console.Read()` method call of the `Program.Main()` method with something different, for example, `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.

#### Reader class

There is a mistake — the `Stream.Read()` method is not guaranteed to read the array of the specified "size" at once (one call), the return value should be used to determine the actual number of bytes read. Let's see the original implementation:

```
int size = ns.ReadByte();
byte[] buff = new byte[size];

// The Stream.Read() method does not guarantee to read the **whole array** "at once".
// Please use the return value of the method.
ns.Read(buff, 0, size);

String message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
```

Corrected version:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper method to read the specified byte array (number of bytes to read is the size of the array).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStream">Input stream.</param>
/// <param name="buffer">The output buffer.</param>
private static void ReadFully(Stream inputStream, byte[] buffer)
{
    if (inputStream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inputStream");
    }

    if (buffer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    }

    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesLeft = buffer.Length;
    if (bytesLeft <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("There is nothing to read for the specified buffer", "buffer");
    }

    while (totalBytesRead < buffer.Length)
    {
        var bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesLeft);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes");
        }
    }
}

public void start()
{
    ...
    int size = ns.ReadByte();
    byte[] buff = new byte[size];
    ReadFully(ns, buff);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buff, false))
    {
        // The StreamReader class is used to extract the UTF-8 string which is encoded with the byte order mark (BOM).
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string message = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Client: {0}", message);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Writer class

First of all, to describe and determine byte the order of the text stream consider including [the byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for each message (for example).

Also, there is a mistake — wrong "buffer length" value is sent. Let's see the original implementation:

```
string Message = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);

// Problem: instead of the length of the string, the size of byte array must be used
// because the UTF-8 encoding is used: generally, string length != "encoded number of bytes".
byte size = (byte)Message.Length;
ns.WriteByte(size);
ns.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
ns.Flush();
```

Corrected version:

```
// UTF-8 with BOM.
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true);

// Buffer encoded as UTF-8 with BOM.
byte[] buff = encoding.GetPreamble()
    .Concat(encoding.GetBytes(message))
    .ToArray();

// Size of the encoded buffer.
byte size = Convert.ToByte(buff.Length);
ns.WriteByte(size);
ns.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
ns.Flush();
```

Alternative corrected version — the `StreamWriter` class is used to encode the string as UTF-8 with the byte order mark (BOM):

```
string message = Console.ReadLine();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(message);
    }
    memoryStream.Flush();

    byte size = Convert.ToByte(memoryStream.Length);
    ns.WriteByte(size);

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    memoryStream.CopyTo(ns);
    ns.Flush();
}
```

### Java Client

#### Read class

First, please consider using `DataInputStream` class because the following statement is not true according to the question:

> An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.
>
> -- [java.io.ObjectInputStream class, Java™ Platform
>   Standard Ed. 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

The instantiation of the stream is almost the same:

```
inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Second, there is a mistake — reading the byte array, but ignoring the return value (actual number of bytes read):

```
String str;
byte size = inStream.readByte();
byte[] buf = new byte[size];

// The InputStream.read() method does not guarantee to read the **whole array** "at once".
// Please use the return value of the method.
inStream.read(buf);
str = new String(buf);
```

Third, as stated above, the byte order mark (BOM) is included.

Corrected version:

```
// Note: inStream must be an instance of DataInputStream class.
byte size = inStream.readByte();

byte[] buf = new byte[size];
// The DataInputStream.readFully() method reads the number of bytes required to fill the buffer entirely.
inStream.readFully(buf);

// Create in-memory stream for the byte array and read the UTF-8 string.
try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    // The BOMInputStream class belongs to Apache Commons IO library.
    BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream, false)) {
    String charsetName = bomInputStream.getBOMCharsetName();

    // The IOUtils class belongs to Apache Commons IO library.
    String message = IOUtils.toString(bomInputStream, charsetName);
    System.out.println("Message form Server : " + message);
}
```

#### Writer class

There is a mistake — the encoding is not specified explicitly. Let's see the original implementation:

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
byte[] buff = str.getBytes();
```

Corrected version:

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
byte[] byteOrderMarkBytes = ByteOrderMark.UTF_8.getBytes();
byte[] stringBytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// The ArrayUtils.addAll() method belongs to Apache Commons Lang library.
byte[] buff = ArrayUtils.addAll(byteOrderMarkBytes, stringBytes);
outStream.writeByte(buff.length);
outStream.write(buff);
outStream.flush();
```

Alternative corrected version — the `ByteArrayOutputStream` class is used to concatenate the arrays:

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] byteOrderMarkBytes = ByteOrderMark.UTF_8.getBytes();
byteArrayOutputStream.write(byteOrderMarkBytes);
byte[] stringBytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byteArrayOutputStream.write(stringBytes);
byteArrayOutputStream.flush();

byte[] buff = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
outStream.writeByte(buff.length);
outStream.write(buff);
outStream.flush();
```

Hope this helps!