# C# .Net framework strings encoding from utf-8 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8

I have application wrote in C#, and this application receives data through network from server using sockets (udp libenet).

In my application I have function to process raw bytes sent in packet.
One of functions is reading string, delimited by \0.

My problem is that I'm sending UTF-8 encoded string by server to C# application, but when I use these strings to display them in controls, I get gibberish instead of polish letters.

Function that reads strings from buffer:

```
public override string ReadString()
{
            
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (true)
    {
        byte b;
        if (Remaining > 0)
            b = ReadByte();
        else
            b = 0;

        if (b == 0) break;

        // Probably here is the problem. Checked other encodings etc., but still same 
        sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { b }, 0, 1));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Function overrides, the one from:

```
public class BitReader : BinaryReader
```

In my application I get:

[image: Polish letters turned into gibberish in dataviewgrid]

Comment: Reasonably copy-paste ready code is available in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523775/c-server-and-java-client-tcp-socket-communication-issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read UTF-8 byte wise as a single character might take more than one byte.

See [How to convert byte[] to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003275/232175) (first read everything into one byte array / List).

Comment: Thank you, works :) Correct solution I'm using is: pushing all bytes into List, then converting it using Encoding.UTF8.GetString(list.ToArray())